# Glue or nails for siding repair?

Tags: siding

I need to patch some wood siding after a roofer modified my roof. I have spare siding from parts and pieces that were removed. Should I glue the siding on or should I nail it in place?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's wood? Looks like fibercement or something to me. In that case, there are very specific fastening techniques and schedules required for warranty and longevity.

Comment: @isherwood That is definitely wood.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest both, but nails should be all you need, provided the pieces span to a stud so as not to break when you attach them. What is strange is there is no sheathing behind the shingles....hmmm

Comment: I suggest aluminum nails to avoid the possibility of rust spots later.  I have galvanized nails in my cement board siding and after 10 years a few showed rust coming through the paint.